# Use Magento’s Core Shopping Cart Model to store/access a list of products

Tags: cart, model, product-list

I’m looking for an elegant way to use Magento’s Core Shopping Cart Model to store/access a list of products on a visitor/customer session WITHOUT displaying the products in the basket and WITHOUT modifying magento's core files.

Comment: Would that be in addition to the regular shopping cart functionality, that is, the customer can add products to the cart which should be visible?

Comment: @Vinai basically, I want to use Magento's Shopping Cart Model to store/access a list of products in an extension that I'm building without affecting the Basket. So when I add a product in my extension I want it to appear only in my extension, not in the basket.

Comment: The quote and quote processing (that is totals calculation, shipping calculation, payment methods, and order placement) are one of the most complex parts of Magento. Unless you want to hook into that functionality as well I'd advise against using the quote for a simple custom list of items. Instead, create your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy! Just add a new quote_item attribute and filter for it in the quote_item_collection. If you need more details, tell me.

You implement your own module. You add a new attribute to the quote_item.

Specifiy a setup script

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version> <!-- this is the version for the install script -->
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <namespace_module_setup> <!-- this is the name of the directory in sql -->
                <setup>
                    <module>Namespace_Module</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Setup</class> <!-- this is important, because in newer versions (magento >1.6?) all sales entity (quote, quote_item, order, order_item, ...) are flat tables -->
                </setup>
            </namespace_module_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

add a install script:

```
app/code/(local|community)/namespace/module/sql/namespace_module_setup/install-1.0.0.php
<?php
/* @var $this Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup */
$this->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute(
    'quote_item',
    'hide',
    array(
         'visible_on_front' => 0,
         'type'             => 'int',
         'label'            => 'Hide in cart',
         'required'         => 0,
         'user_defined'     => 1
// other values and config settings can be seen here: /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php:592
    )
);

$this->endSetup();
```

Then you set the new attribute on the quote_item after you added it to the cart $quoteItem->setHide(1); it is saved automatically (clean the cache!).

And then you can use any event, e.g. `eav_collection_abstract_load_before`:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
            <observers>
                <your_name>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>namespace_module/observer</class>
                    <method>eavCollectionAbstractLoadBefore</method>
                </your_name>
            </observers>
        </eav_collection_abstract_load_before>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

In this method you check whether it is a `Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Quote_Item_Collection` and then you add a `addAttributeToFilter('hide', 1)`

then the items are not loaded.

Comment: can you be more specific ? How is the Basket going to know that I've added a quote_item attribute to certain products and not display those products in the basket, without changing the core files ?

Comment: edited the post.

Comment: I got everything working besides the observer method. I tried something like: 
`$collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
if ($collection instanceof Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Quote_Item_Collection) {
   print_r($collection);
  }` but I don't get any output...

Comment: try with Mage::log(get_class($collection)); maybe it is `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection`

Comment: it's `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`, but this one is also triggered in the category page, so I will have to check if the page is checkout/cart.

Comment: I am wondering if it's possible to create a new instance of the cart and force it to save the items in another table ?

Comment: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` is wrong. before the products are loaded for the quoteItems, the quoteItems themselves are loaded with their collection. And no, you can't just change the table. What you can do is implement your own logic, have a table to save the productId, customer_id, store_id or something like this.

Comment: I used another event to grab the `Quote_Item_Collection` but now I get the following error: `Call to undefined method Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Quote_Item_Collection::addAttributeToFilter()`